# Bash if condition

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I'd like to write a bash script that looks at `security list-keychains` to see if there is a keychain named appledev.  If there is not a keychain I'd like to create it with this `security create-keychain -p foo appledev`

I was trying todo something like this but it's ridiculously incorrect.

```
APPLEDEVKEYCHAIN=`security list-keychains | grep appledev`
if [[$APPLEDEVKEYCHAIN -eq 1]]; then
  echo "Using keychain ${APPLEDEVKEYCHAIN}"
else
  echo "Creating Keychain appledev"
  security create-keychain -p foo appledev
fi
exit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` returns a success exit code if it finds anything. The following would work:

```
if security list-keychains | grep -q appledev; then
  echo "Got keychain"
else
  echo "Creating keychain"
  security create-keychain -p foo appledev
fi
```

(`-q` is the "quiet" switch to `grep`; this prevents `grep` from printing anything.)

Some other things that might help with your Bash shell scripting:

1. Backquotes are dated and error-prone. Use `$(command)` instead.
2. When using command substitution (`$(command)` (or, heaven forbid, backquotes)), put double quotes around the substitution.
3. The double-bracket special command needs spaces around the `[[` and `]]` in order to work.